# writing and reading from windows registry C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Programmatically, I want to keep and save count of something (will be writing and updating value of that count to registry), but that shouldn't go away (delete) from registry even when uninstalling and re-installing the windows Form application  using MSI setup i created.

Even on re-install, i want to read that old value from registry.
It's something kind of i want to keep track of that value always.

How can i make it possible?

Comment: Take a look at this artice http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: Thanks @Learner, is it feasible using MSI Installer ??

Comment: How are you creating the MSI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Registry` class in the .NET Framework.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry
    .CurrentUser
    .OpenSubKey(@"Software\YourApplication")
    .SetValue("ConfigValue1", example);
```

*(of course you have to create the "YourApplication" key before. This is just an example)*

It's just as simple as that and pretty self explanatory, too.

Also, these values don't get deleted, unless you tell your installer to. Since you haven't told us much about your installer, I figured your main issue here was to handle Registry writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create your registry keys in your deployment project getting it to leave keys alone during uninstall is pretty easy.

In the Registry editor window for the installer select the key you want to remain and open the properties tab. In here there are two properties **DeleteAtUninstall** which determines whether or not the uninstaller removes the key. and **Transitive** which determines whether a reinstall will recheck the key. I believe this is also used if you have your MSI repair an installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create the registry key in the MSI (create it at run time if it's not there instead) and you don't let the MSI know about it then it won't be removed by the uninstaller. Same as with files you create at runtime.

You need to decide if you want to save the value per user or per machine

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
...
//var root = Registry.LocalMachine
var root = Registry.CurrentUser;
//Use Create Sub Key to 'Creates a new subkey or opens an existing subkey for write access'
root.CreateSubKey("YourKey").SetValue("MyInt", val);
```